# Android studio images

Tags: android, android-image

I want to store images for my quizz app on android with ArrayList.The images must be stored in the folder drawable.
Is someone can explain me how to do this?
Thank you

Comment: what does it mean store images on android ?

Comment: try saving your images in the drawable folder?

Comment: It for a quizz app.I will add images in in the drawable folder.And when i start the quizz i will load the image in an imageview and the image will appear with a question

Comment: yes and when i start the quizz the image will appear

Comment: @AmidouFlorianTouré so, what is the question? Loading image in the `ImageView` or putting images in the drawable folder?

Answer (score 0):

Pate your Images in the drawable folder and access them from your activity using R.drawable.imagenames.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the images in your drawable folder.

Create a ArrayList in your code and add all the images to the arraylist

```
ArrayList<View> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
imageList.add(image1);
imageList.add(image2);
...and so on
```

Comment: Ok thanks but when i do imageList.add(image) i have an error

Comment: The method dosen't exist

Comment: Must i create a void method to add the questions?What will be in this method?

Comment: ArrayList<QuizImage> imageList = new ArrayList<QuizImage>();
        imageList.add(image1);
image1 is my Imageview i want to change the images for all questions

Comment: Oh god! your declaration is incorrect. it should be : ArrayList<View> QuizImage = new ArrayList<View>();

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> array_image = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        array_image.add(R.drawable.place2);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.quizz);

Comment: how can i change the images for a specific question?

Comment: By removing the image at the particular index and replacing it with the required image in the array.